# FullCalendar Data Passing Syntax

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-3

I am displaying an event based on Current time comparing with database.
Eg.
Current time: 16:00
From time: 16:00
To Time: 17:00

If Current time exists then it will display data on calendar or not.
I am having issues with it.Whenever my code goes in else section if current time does not matches it creates false array.

```
$json = array();
        $start=$_REQUEST['start'];
        $end=$_REQUEST['end'];
        if($start != '' && $end != '')
        {
            $where="(from_date BETWEEN '$start' and '$end') or (to_date BETWEEN '$start' and '$end')";
            $finalArray=[];
            //$json=$this->Rates_model->getAnyData($where,'','','','','');
            $json=$this->Rates_model->getAnyData();
            if(!empty($json))
            {

                foreach ($json as $key => $js) {

                    $finalArray[$key]['id']= $js->id;
                    $from= array('time'=>gmdate("h:i", strtotime($js->from_time)));
                    $to= array('time'=>gmdate("h:i", strtotime($js->to_time)));


                    $date1 = date("h:i a");
                    $date2 = date('h:i a', strtotime($js->from_time));
                    $date3 = date('h:i a', strtotime($js->to_time));
                    if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3)
                    {
                        $finalArray[$key]['start']= date('Y-d-m',strtotime($js->from_date))."T".$js->from_time;
                        $finalArray[$key]['end']=date('Y-d-m',strtotime($js->to_date))."T".$js->to_time;
                        if(!empty($js->rate_per_hour) && !empty($js->rate_per_mile))
                        {
                            $fullTitle="Hour: ".$js->rate_per_hour.",Mile: ".$js->rate_per_mile;
                        }
                        elseif(!empty($js->rate_per_hour) && empty($js->rate_per_mile)){
                            $fullTitle="Hour: ".$js->rate_per_hour;
                        }
                        elseif(empty($js->rate_per_hour) && !empty($js->rate_per_mile)){
                           $fullTitle="Mile: ".$js->rate_per_mile;
                        }
                        $finalArray[$key]['title']=$fullTitle;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         echo "No Event has been Set";
                     }
 }

                echo json_encode($finalArray);
```

My JSON Response if time exists:

```
[{"id":"1","start":"2017-03-11T13:00:00","end":"2017-03-11T17:00:00","title":"Hour: 0.99,Mile: 0.99"},{"id":"14","start":"2017-03-11T15:00:00","end":"2017-03-11T17:30:00","title":"Hour: 11.00,Mile: 11.00"},{"id":"15","start":"2017-03-12T15:25:00","end":"-0001-30-11T17:30:00","title":"Hour: 22.00,Mile: 22.00"}]
```

If current time does not matches then
    No Event has been Set

```
[{"id":"1","start":"2017-03-11T13:00:00","end":"2017-03-11T17:00:00","title":"Hour: 0.99,Mile: 0.99"},{"id":"14"},{"id":"15","start":"2017-03-12T15:25:00","end":"-0001-30-11T17:30:00","title":"Hour: 22.00,Mile: 22.00"}]
```

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

Comment: what do you mean by false array?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your code adds the **id** of the event to the **finalArray** before checking if the event is with in a particular hour. Place

> $finalArray[$key]['id']= $js->id;

inside of

> if ($date1 > $date2 && $date1 < $date3){

statement and it should work fine. Hope this helps.